# How to get the value from anchor tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="" id="a1">myval</a>
```

How to get the value which is in between anchor tag ie; here "myval" and then specify that value to a hidden box.I tried do it with my piece of code but couldn't figure it out.pls help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#a1").click(function(e){
            //var str=$("#a1").getVal();        
            alert('hello');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the acronym "wtf" comes to mind? can you try formatting your questions properly, put in an example of an anchor tag and what you want from it and what you mean by a 'hidden box'

Answer (score 18):

```
var a1_text = $('#a1').text();
```

Answer (score 6):

`var a_href = $("#a1").attr("href");`

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="" id="a1">myval</a>
```

you can use  `var yourValue= $('#a1').text();`
it will works fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the innertext of the anchor tag and [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to store the value to a textbox.

```
$(function(){
    $("#a1").click(function(){
        $("#yourtextbox").val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$('#a1').click(function(){
   $(this).text();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#a1").click(function(e){
           var str=$("#a1").html();        
            alert(str);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

"myVal" is not the link element's "value". It is the text that forms a child element inside it.

Use:

```
$(function(){
    $('#a1').click(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```