# Grab the href and text of <a> tags from the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I have a page with multiple links (`<a>` tag with a specific class-selector, e.g. `"class=my-link"`), I need to grab the text of these links (the content between `<a>` and `</a>` tags) and their `"href"` attribute and output it into a JavaScript multidimensional object, giving an ID number (just increment, 01, 02, 03 and so on).

Example.

Original page with links:

```
<a href="red" class="my-link">Apples are red</a>
<a href="green" class="my-link">Grass is green</a>
```

Output:

```
var mylinks = [
  { "LinkID": "01", "LinkHref": "red", "LinkText": "Apples are red" },
  { "LinkID": "02", "LinkHref": "green", "LinkText": "Grass is green" }
];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from anchor tag using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180306/how-to-get-the-value-from-anchor-tag-using-jquery)

Comment: You will need `.each()`, `.html()`, and `.attr()`. Now try something and come back when you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
var arr = [];
$.each( $("a.my-link"), function( i, element ) { // iterate over all anchor elements with class my-link
   arr.push({
       "LinkID" : i+1,
       "LinkHref" : $(element).attr("href"),
       "LinkText" : $(element).html()
   });
});
```